# Extract the RHS string by removing the whitespaces in between

Tags: linux, shell

```
dvc0723f380w2_high = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=dvc0723f380w2.us.com))(connect_data=(service_name=dvc0723f380w2_high.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=no)))
```

For extracting RHS, I have used -

```
str=$(grep '_high' file.txt)
CONNECTION_STRING=`echo ${str} | cut -d '=' -f2-`;
```

But this is bringing the 2 whitespaces present after `=` sign. As a result when I am trying to pass this value as a parameter while creating JSON, it's not coming properly.

Please suggest a way to remove whitespaces from RHS end.

Comment: Meenal, ignoring your code for a moment, what do you actually want to extract from the example data? You talk about "_the RHS string_"; is that `no` or `ssl_server_dn_match=no` or even `security=(ssl_server_dn_match=no)`? Or did "_RHS string_" refer to everything after the first `=`?

Comment: "_this is bringing the 2 whitespaces present after = sign_" - there isn't anywhere in the data you show that has two whitespaces after an `=` symbol

Answer (score 0):

If you type backticks into the editor here, it'll highlight the surrounded text like `this`. So I think you meant your command now is

```
str=$(grep '_high' file.txt) 
CONNECTION_STRING=`echo ${str} | cut -d '=' -f2-`;
```

You could instead do

```
CONNECTION_STRING=$(grep "_high" file.txt | awk '{print $3}')
```

You could use `cut` by piping through another cut command that uses `-d" "`.

Comment: the above did not give any output when I tried echo $CONNECTION_STRING.

Comment: could you please elaborate how can we use another cut, I can try that.

Comment: In the future, it would also help to explain why what the OP is trying is not working.

Comment: The OP's code, as written, failed due to a syntax error, `-f2-`, and it also did the cut on `=`, which split off the second half _starting_ with a space. The request appears to be to take everything after the _first_ `=`, excluding the space. This can be accomplished with `grep "_high" file.txt | cut -d '=' -f2-99 | cut -d ' ' -f2-99`. My awk command was in error. It would have printed everything after the second `=`, excluding the space; I also had an extra nested `$()`, which was a typo, that I've removed.